# Select all values that also exists with specific other value

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql like e.g.

```
      --------------------------
Line  |  category  |  product  |
      ==========================
 1    |  1         |  500      |
 2    |  10        |  500      |
 3    |  1         |  510      |
 4    |  11        |  510      |
 5    |  2         |  520      |
 6    |  10        |  520      |
      --------------------------
```

Now I was wondering if its possible to select category from line 2 and 4 because they also exist with the category value 1 in the table.

I tried some stuff like

```
select 
    max(categorie),
    product
from 
    products 
group by
    product
```

but this brings up all results. even those having a product that has 2 as category.

Expected output is:

```
| category |
|==========|
| 10       |
| 11       |
------------
```

Comment: please show us the expected output

Comment: how can Line 1,2 and 4 are related , they do not have category or product value in common , can you elaborate more?

Comment: guess you read my post wrong. I only want line 2 and 4 because both products have an entry with category 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be self joining the table, so that each `product` gets matched with the rows of the same `product` that have 1 as `category`

```
select  t1.category
from    yourTable t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t1.product = t2.product and
        t1.category <> t2.category
where   t2.category = 1
```